# Addressable memory in MU0: 12bit or 16bit?

Tags: assembly, arm

I'm studying about MU0.

The book says that MU0 is a 16 bit machine with a 12 bit address space and it can address up to 2^16 bit of memory.  (4 bits for opcode)
Is it true that it can address up to 16 bit memory though it has 12 bit address space?

Answer (score 0):

Correct, but these 16 bits will be split (4bit opcode). So just 4K is usable memory (2^12).

Comment: A clarification would be that the MU0 can address 4096 16-bit words which would be 8192 bytes of memory.